# setState with firebase realtime database in react native

Tags: react-native

I have experiance in iOS native development and I am now trying to build my first app on react-native.

I am trying to setSate when I receive data from firebase database as bellow:

```
state = {
remainingSeconds: 5,
dataArray: [],
};

componentDidMount() {
// Get data from firebase
this.getData(); 
}

getData() {
// Set the configuration for your app
var config = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXX",
  databaseURL:  "XXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: ""
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();

// Get data
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('Users');
usersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {

  this.setState({
    dataArray: snapshot.val()
  })
});
};
```

I get the following error:

[image]

any one can help about that?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the issue is that your callback function where you call `setState` does not have the same context as it's parent function.

All you need to do to fix this is convert the callback function from the standard function declaration to an arrow function.

```
// Get data
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('Users');
usersRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  this.setState({
    dataArray: snapshot.val()
  })
});
```

That should give you the right context so that `this` means the same thing in the callback function as in the parent function.

Comment: Thanks bro. You just saved me after 2 hours of googling. But can you explain more why this situations arises pls. i would like to understand better. PS; still new in React Native

Comment: @FONGOHMARTIN when defining callback functions in JavaScript with the `function` keyword you do not automatically get the parent context (the value of `this`) inside the callback function. In order to get that context correctly you can use an arrow function as it doesn't have its own context so it just uses the context the parent function has.

Comment: Wow, @jasonmerino , thanks alot for that explanation. Its helped me understand now why that behavior. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you've lost reference of 'this' because of scope.

Not the prettiest solution, but I hope this might help:

```
// Get data
var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('Users');

let snapshotVal; 
usersRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
 snapshotVal = snapshot.val()

 });
};
this.setState({
  dataArray: snapshotVal
})
```